# Как прикрепить 1 entyti ко многим Entities

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2, relation

Задача создать комментарии для страниц, постов, портфолио... пользователей, ответы на сами комментарии.
Как правильно оформить? 
Можно ли targetEntity передавать строчку через запятую?

```
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="object_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $object;
```

Answer (score 2):

Через запятую в `targetEntity` перечислить несколько сущностей нельзя - не забывайте что Вы ссылаетесь скорее всего на разные таблицы в БД.

Насколько я понял, вы хотите перечислить в `targetEntity` все сущности, под которыми Вы хотите размещать комментарии. Причем насколько я могу восстановить контекст по отрывку кода, данное поле и аннотация находятся в классе `Comment`.

**Пофантазируем...**

Теоритически можно сослаться на несколько разных сущностей, с помощью одного поля с помощью наследования. В **Doctrine**(*ORM*, которую использует *Symfony*) есть различные стратегии хранения иерархии классов, в том числе и такая, в которой всё дерево классов хранится в одной таблице, которая содержит **объединение** полей (т.е. множество всех полей всех классов) и при выборе элементов одного класса, выбираются только поля объявленные в данном классе и унаследованные от родителей(но не поля соседних классов).

Т.е. есть подобная иерархия классов:

```
Record  
      |--  Page
      |--  Post
      |--  News
      |--  Review
      |--  etc...
```

И Вы устанавливаете связь между классом `Comment` и родительским классом `Record`. Тогда Ваше поле с аннотацией сможет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Record", inversedBy="comments")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="record_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $record;
```

Стоит отметить, что **не стоит городить наследование, в случае где его быть не должно** и хранить все сущности в одной таблице - **это безумие**. И даже если на момент реализации, несколько классов допустимо будет подогнать под одного предка, это не значит что в будущем не появится необходимости прикрутить комментарии к другой сущности, которая не имеет ничего общего с предыдущими.
Поэтому данныый вариант, однозначно, отметается.

Возможен и обратный вариант с наследованием:

```
Comment  
      |--  CommentToPage
      |--  CommentToPost
      |--  CommentToNews
      |--  CommentToReview
      |--  etc...
```

В данном варианте классы `Page`, `Post`, `News`, `Review`, etc. не наследуются от единого предка и хранятся в разных таблицах, но разделены классы комментариев, в каждом из которых есть поля содержимого комментария и времени публикации, унаследованных от родительского класса `Comment` и по одному полю со ссылкой на конкретную сущность у каждого из дочерних классов(`CommentToPage`,etc.).

В таком случае в каждом классе будет поле со ссылкой:

```
class CommentToPage extends Comment{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $page;
}
...
class CommentToPost extends Comment{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;
}
```

**Суровая реальность**

На деле же, просмотрев огромное количество проектов убеждаюсь, что практически все считают, что "*овчинка выделки не стоит*", и не парятся с наследованием и хранением нескольких сущностей в одной таблице. Встречается два варианта:

1.Хранение в классе комментария нескольких ссылок(наиболее частый вариант):

```
class Comment{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Page", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $page;
    //...
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Post", inversedBy="comments")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="post_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $post;
}
```

2.Гораздо реже используют несколько классов комментариев, хранящихся в разных таблицах и естественно дублирующих поля содержимого комментария и времени.

В этом случае много копипасты и откровенно говоря придётся чуть больше постучать палчиками по клавиатуре, поэтому предыдущий вариант наиболее популярен.

---

**Суть**

Главное - понимать суть. А суть в том, что за всеми сущностями, классами и аннотациями стоят реальные таблицы в базе данных, поля которых ссылаются на строчки в других таблицах и имеют внешние ключи. Помня это и представляя структуру таблиц в базе данных будет  проще создавать `Сущности` и связи между ними.

Напоследок несколько ссылок:

- [Doctrine: Association
  mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)
- [Doctrine: Inheritance
  mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)
  (Наследование)